# How can I record audio using Action script then upload it to server?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

First is there any technique for using Action Script for recording sound from microphone? 
If yes. How?
Then one he record I'll upload it to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flash.media.Microphone` is the class you're looking for.

The static function `Microphone.getMicrophone()` returns a reference to a `Microphone` object for capturing audio. To begin capturing the audio, you must attach the `Microphone`object to a `NetStream` object (see `NetStream.attachAudio()`).

There's at least one example in the [LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/). Start at `flash.media.Microphone`.