# How can I record audio in a web app client side and save it in a web server?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, flash, silverlight, audio

I have a requirement to do a flash program or something like that (not necessarily flash, it can be javascript or something in aspnet) that allow me to save audio in the client side of a web app, and save it on a file in the server side of the web app.

I've been searching a lot in google, and all I've found are just old questions, but no answers that fulfill my question

Please I need help!

Ive found [this](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/microphone.htm) but the only thing that it does its to recognize the microphone, I need the hability of saving the audio file, by the way the server is implemented in aspnet

Comment: Also is it in VB or something else ?

Comment: the server is in ASPNET c#, If it can be done in VB, I think it can be done in c#, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Duplicate (when tagged with Flash)

[How can I record audio using Action script then upload it to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311167/how-can-i-record-audio-using-action-script-then-upload-it-to-server)

> The static function
>   `Microphone.getMicrophone()` returns a
>   reference to a `Microphone` object for
>   capturing audio. To begin capturing
>   the audio, you must attach the
>   `Microphone` object to a `NetStream`
>   object (see `NetStream.attachAudio()`).
>
> There's at least one example in the
>   [LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/). Start at
>   flash.media.Microphone.

via [@aaaidan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311167/how-can-i-record-audio-using-action-script-then-upload-it-to-server/329893#329893)

Answer (score 0):

This is like asking everybody to do your entire homework for you.
You need to break the problem down into smaller achievable pieces/goals.

Example:

1. Record audio
2. Send to web server

Now you'll most likely get better results when you google it up.

Comment: thanks, but Ive done that, I've found how to record audio in different kind of ways, like silverlight, but that feauture is too younger, and less compatible, flash is more supported, but Ive only found an example that tells me how to record, but I dont know if its capable to comunicate with other platforms, because I have the way to save it, my server has a web service, It receives a base64 string and it saves the file, in fact, the thing that I want to know is how to get the byte stream from the recording in flash and send it to the web server